# PHP Return the value of cookie in conditional statement

Tags: wordpress, function

I would like to use the add_filter to insert a function in wordpress (inside functions.hp) but i would like this filter to be enabled only if the ($_COOKIE['country']) returns "DK" (for Danemark)

In advance, thank you!

```
if ($_COOKIE['country']) == 'DK' { 
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
}
```

Comment: So, what is the issue in that code?

Comment: @GolezTrol, the syntax, for one thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cookie doesn't exist, `$_COOKIE['country']` is not set and reading it throws an error. You can suppress this in various ways, for instance

Using the suppression operator:

```
if ((string)@$_COOKIE['country'] === 'DK') {
  add_filter( ... );
}
```

Using `isset` or `array_key_exists`:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['country']) && $_COOKIE['country'] === 'DK') {
  add_filter( ... );
}

if (array_key_exists('country', $_COOKIE) && $_COOKIE['country'] === 'DK') {
  add_filter( ... );
}
```

I think `array_key_exists` is the purest form, but most people use `isset` because it it shorter and easier.